# Lebesgue measure of a set $A \in (a,b)$ can be bounded by $b+a + |t|$ where $t$ is a translation constant

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-sets

Let $A \subset (a,b)$ a Lebesgue measurable set such that $A\cap (A+t) = \emptyset$.   Show that $2m(A) \leq b-a + |t|$.
I've been trying to get the inequality by writing $m(A\cup (A+t)) = m(A) + m(A+t) = 2m(A)$ but don't know if this a correct procedure.

Comment: You are in the right direction. In fact, $m(A\cup (A+t)) = m(A) + m(A+t) = 2m(A)$. Now, suppose $t>0$. Can you prove that $ A\cup (A+t) \subseteq (a, b+t)$?  If so, we get $$2m(A) = m(A\cup (A+t)) \leqslant b+t -a= b-a + |t|.$$ Can you adapt that argument for the case $t<0$?